# python package import on windows

Tags: python

i am working on windows 7 platform,please tell me how to install and configure third party packages,to use that package in some other python program

Thanks mukthyar

Comment: Google for the fulltext of your question and you will get the perfect answer with the first three hits.

Answer (score 1):

["Installing Python Modules"](http://docs.python.org/install/index.html)